# how to get attributes from this javascript array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, next.js

How to get attribute **title** from this array which has only one data record,
I just want to print title, for example
If I write **console.log(data)** it shows the  result as shown in picture below, but when I write **conosle.log(data[0].attributes.title)** it shows 0 is undefined, how can I print **title** in console.log?

**Full Code**

```js
   
const PostPage = ({ slug }) => {
 // console.log(slug)
  const QUERY =  gql `query getPosts($slug: String!){
    posts(filters: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
      data {
        id
        attributes {
          title
          slug
          description
            }
          }
        }
      }
  
    `;
  const { data, loading,error } = useQuery(QUERY,{ variables: {slug}}); 
  console.log(data)

  return (
   
        <div class="card p-1">
          
        </div>
  );
};

export default PostPage;
export async function getServerSideProps({ query }) {
  const slug = query.slug
  console.log(slug)
  return { props: { slug } };
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please give a [mre] **as text**.

Comment: just want like console.log(data[0].attributes.title)? but not able to print title, it shows that 0 is undefind

Comment: So [edit] the question to give a MRE per [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want:

```
console.log(data.posts.data[0].attributes.title)
```

updated based on your comment that the log in the image is of 'data'.

**update 2**: because data is populated using a hook that is probably asynchronous, you should expect it may be undefined or null until some promise is resolved.

```
if (data) {
  console.log(data.posts.data[0].attributes.title)
} else {
  console.log('Zzz... waiting for data')
}
```

Comment: not showing the result I want , it shows posts is not defined

Comment: This answer is not correct , I have this code "

const { data, loading,error } = useQuery(QUERY,{ variables: {slug}});
console.log(data)"

Comment: updated answer.

Comment: Still it shows "Cannot read property 'posts' of undefined"

Comment: Still it show "TypeError: Cannot read property 'posts' of undefined"

Comment: Can't answer the question any better without seeing more code and/or the data returned. Update the question with additional details. From what you wrote, the above should work.

Comment: Thanks @Dave , this was a problem of promise resolve

Answer (score 0):

posts.data[0].attributes.title = "Trump got some money..."
data[0].attributes.title = undefined